# Clicking on next/link causing an issue in getInitialProps

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm trying to add a link to redirect users to the create page,
But when I clicked on the link I got the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cookies')
```

Link code :

```
<Link href={link}>Add New Employee</Link>
```

getInitialProps // _app.tsx

```
MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context: any) => {
    const {req, res, pathname} = context.ctx;
    const {language, auth_key} = req.cookies;

    return {
        lang: language ?? 'ar',
        token: auth_key ?? null,
    }
};
```

Comment: `req` is undefined because there is no `req` on the client. But what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to write isomorphic code inside `MyApp.getInitialProps` because that code can run both on the server (during first page load) or on the client (during client-side navigations).

From [`getInitialProps`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-initial-props) documentation:

> For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will run on the server
> only. `getInitialProps` will then run on the client when navigating to a
> different route via the `next/link` component or by using `next/router`.
> However, if `getInitialProps` is used in a custom `_app.js`, and the page
> being navigated to implements `getServerSideProps`, then `getInitialProps`
> will run on the server.

---

Here's a possible implementation to get around your error. It checks if `req` is defined before accessing `req.cookies`. If it is, then the cookies are retrieved from `document` instead.

```js
// Get cookie from `document` on the client-side
const getCookie = (name) => {
    const match = document.cookie?.match(new RegExp(`(^| )${name}=([^;]+)`));
    return match?.[2];
};

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const { req } = context.ctx;
    const language = req ? req.cookies.language : getCookie('language');
    const auth_key = req ? req.cookies.auth_key : getCookie('auth_key');

    return {
        lang: language ?? 'ar',
        token: auth_key ?? null,
    }
};
```